# Change css color just recently clicked element

Tags: jquery

I made ​​an accordion menu that works perfectly, but I would like to change the color of some text when it is expanded.
I would like the text "h2 a" to be in red color  when the accordion is expanded and blue when it is collapsed.

This is my code, which is currently not working:

HTML:

```
<div class="accordionHead">
  <h2><a href="#">New Features<i class="dct"></i></a></h2>
</div>
<div class="accordionHead">
  <h2><a href="#">New Features<i class="dct"></i></a></h2>
</div>
...
```

jquery

```
  $('.accordionHead').click(function () {
      $('.pane').slideUp('slow');
      $(this).find('h2 a').css("color", "red");

      if ($(this).next().is(':hidden') == true) {
          $(this).next().slideDown('slow');
          $(this).find('h2 a').css("color", "blue"); // this dont work
      }

      event.preventDefault();
  });
```

Comment: show your html as well.

Comment: can you come up with a fiddle for the same?

Comment: `$(this).next().is(':hidden')` doesn't really make any sense. Are are all your `.accordionHead` hidden?

Comment: its working:http://jsfiddle.net/ehsansajjad465/0hoyd3xc/3/

Comment: how to do an if statement to disable other color "a"?

Comment: you want to remove color of other ``a``

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to chain a function on animation complete of your slideDown event:

```
var _this = $(this);
_this.next().slideDown('slow', 
    function() {
          _this.find('h2 a').css("color", "blue"); 
});
```

Jquery reference here: http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement to check hidden was kind of not working (I used the visible attribute) as well as you can select the other accordionHead using the [siblings()](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) jquery function.

JS Code:

```
$('.accordionHead').click(function () {
      $('.pane').slideUp('slow');
      $(this).find('h2 a').css("color", "red");

      if ($(this).parents().find('.accordionHead').is(':visible') == true) {
          $(this).next().slideDown('slow');
          $(this).siblings().find('h2 a').css("color", "blue");
      }

      event.preventDefault();
});
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92p3enp3/)

Comment: I put your code, the accordion  works fine but the color don't change only make red all clicked http://i.imgur.com/f1KDzZq.jpg
Thanks